# Qt OSX Incorrect Mouse Behavior

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, opencv, user-interface

My application uses OpenCV, OpenGL, and Qt to display a webcam feed. It works perfectly on Ubuntu (clicking buttons works properly), but on OSX there seems to be a UI problem. The window displays, but I can't click and I quickly just get the loading spinning pinwheel and it doesn't stop until I force quit the application. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: Is your application enclosed in a proper app bundle?  For whatever reason OSX seems unwilling to give an event loop to a raw executable run via `./appname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a timer to the initialization of my gui widget:

```
m_timer = new QTimer();
connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(gotNewImage()));
m_timer->start(1);
```

where gotNewImage() is the function I call to grab a new image.